# Randomly failing JS tests

Tags: javascript, promise

Hi I'm getting this error when running my tests I've read up on the promises and done I'm still unsure where to put it in my test or is it best to do a before each instead to save repetition? Where and what would be the best way to implement the done promise?

Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure 
"done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

```
    const chakram = require('chakram');
const expect = chakram.expect;


describe("Json assertions", function () {
    it("Should return the matching test file and have a 200 response", function () {

        let expected = require('../../test/fixtures/testfile.json');
        let response = chakram.get("http://test");
        expect(response).to.have.json(expected);
        expect(response).to.have.status(200);
        return chakram.wait();
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, what if `http://test` is not available? Will the promise ever resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with `chakram`, but generally here is a pattern that should work with testing your promises (using `done`):

```
describe('Test Suite', function() {
  it('should do something...', function(done) {
    const testValue = 'testValue';
    someAsyncFunction(testValue).then(function(result) {
      result.should.have.property('foo');
      result.should.have.property('bar');
      done();
    });
  ]);
});
```

Now for what you have, it looks like the [docs for Chakram](http://dareid.github.io/chakram) show how to test with promises (under the Promises header). So your adapted code would be something like:

```
const chakram = require('chakram');
const expect = chakram.expect;

describe("Json assertions", function () {
  it("should...", function () {
    let expected = require('../../test/fixtures/testfile.json');
    chakram.get("http://test").then(function(response) {
      expect(response).to.have.json(expected);
      expect(response).to.have.status(200);
    });
  });
});
```

Again, I do not know that library, but if your test runner still complains about the `done`, add `done` like so:

```
describe("Json assertions", function () {
  it("should...", function (done) {
    let expected = require('../../test/fixtures/testfile.json');
    chakram.get("http://test").then(function(response) {
      expect(response).to.have.json(expected);
      expect(response).to.have.status(200);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Edit: `done` was in `describe` block, and should have been in `it`.

Comment: Thank you. This was very useful.